# copy QPixmap of one Qlabel to another Qlabel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel, qpixmap

I am trying to add a `QPixmap` to a `QLabel` taken from another `QLabel` but there is an error :

Here is the code

```
const QPixmap *tempPix = new QPixmap("");
tempPix = (label1->pixmap());
label2->setPixmap(tempPix);  //error cannot convert from const QPixmap* to const QPixmap&
```

and if I do it like this:

```
const QPixmap tempPix("");
tempPix = (label1->pixmap()); //error cannot convert QPixmap and QPixmap*
label2->setPixmap(tempPix);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy data from a pointer object to an object you must use the *

```
QPixmap tempPix;
if(label1->pixmap()){
    tempPix = *label1->pixmap();
    label2->setPixmap(tempPix);
 }
```

Comment: this works fine but i want to do it using a temp pixmap

Comment: ok thank you works good but it means i cant initialize tempPix on a separate line and give it any value further.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in a single line as follows:

```
label2->setPixmap(*label1->pixmap());
```

Note that `*` will convert the pointer returned by `pixmap()` to a reference. The difference between both is explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Note that in your first example, the constructed `QPixmap` in the first line is never used and a memory leak occurs. The second line changes the pointer value, not the data of the newly constructed object.

Comment: Unfortunately, `QLabel::pixmap()` suffers from an API bug since `pixmap` is a value property, yet `pixmap()` and returns a pointer instead of the value itself. The pointer can be null, and this code has undefined behavior when `label1` has no pixmap :(

Comment: The safest way is indeed to check if `pixmap` is not null, but if the OP knows this is not the case, the check is not needed.